# How can I start a Robot Framework test in a Jenkinsfile using a robot framework docker image?

Tags: docker, robotframework

In the Jenkinsfile I would like to use an existing Robot framework docker image. The Docker image that is pretty complete for browser testing is: ppodgorsek/robot-framework

An example of the use is:

```
docker run \
    -v <local path to the reports' folder>:/opt/robotframework/reports:Z \
    -v <local path to the test suites' folder>:/opt/robotframework/tests:Z \
    ppodgorsek/robot-framework:<version>
```

How can I start a Robot Framework test?

Comment: On the behalf of the downvoter: your question appears to be far too broad and seems that it can not be answered simply. If you have an example what you have tried maybe someone can help you to make it correct?

Comment: Ok, thanks, will keep that in mind!

Comment: Made the question specific! The answer consisted literally of 1 action to start the Robot Framework test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution-1**: thanks to @parasit I found 'ppodgorsek/robot-framework'.

You can start a Robot Framework test from a Jenkinsfile with this pipeline code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: "master", url:'https://github.com/johan974/robot-framework-demo1.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps{
                sh 'docker run -v ${PWD}/reports:/opt/robotframework/reports:Z -v ${PWD}/Tests:/opt/robotframework/tests:Z \
                            -e BROWSER=chrome ppodgorsek/robot-framework:latest'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archive (includes: 'reports/*.html')
        }
    }
}
```

If you have these steps (including post), then you can find the results in the famous log.html en report.html files as shown below:

[image]

If you face problems showing the RF results, you can execute the followin script in your Jenkins > manage jenkins > script console:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP","sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self' data: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ;")
```

**UPDATE-2**: using the much smaller Robot Framework image I could start Robot Frameworkrunning. It complains about the chromedriver not installed. This script is shown below. It could be enough when you don't have to test using a browser.

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'manycoding/robotframework'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: "master", url:'https://github.com/johan974/robot-framework-demo1.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps{
                sh 'chmod a+x ./run-tests.sh && ./run-tests.sh'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archive (includes: 'reports/*.html')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? I dont have idea how robotframework works :)

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'ppodgorsek/robot-framework'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: "master", credentialsId: "jenkins-key", url:'ssh://git@github.org/mysupercode/'

            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps{
                sh 'do_super_tests.sh'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            archive (includes: 'mytestfolder/mytest.html')
        }
    }
}
```